# After I modify Settings at runtime and I close my application these settings are gone

Tags: c#, .net, settings

Im using in my application built in settings and Im reading settings in this way

```
variable = (bool)Settings.Default["GetHKAlt"];
```

and saving in this way:

```
Settings.Default["GetHKAlt"] = variable;
```

But after I modifying the settings at runtime and I close my application these settings are gone, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) site says that this settings are saved in app.config file, but I do not see this file anywhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [article you linked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> You **must also explicitly call the Save method** of this wrapper
>   class in order **to persist the user settings**. You usually do this in
>   the Closing event handler of the main form. The following Visual C#
>   example shows a call to the Save method.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```